# macroexpand doseq in Babashka vs in Clojure

Tags: clojure, babashka, clojure-core

In Babashka v0.6.2, I can call macroexpand on the [for](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) macro and the output is something like this:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(for [i (range 10)] i))
(clojure.core/let [iter__1755__auto__ (clojure.core/fn iter__147 [s__148] (clojure.core/lazy-seq (loop [s__148 s__148] (clojure.core/let [s__148 (clojure.core/seq s__148)] (clojure.core/when s__148 (if (clojure.core/chunked-seq? s__148) (clojure.core/let [c__1753__auto__ (clojure.core/chunk-first s__148) size__1754__auto__ (clojure.core/int (clojure.core/count c__1753__auto__)) b__150 (clojure.core/chunk-buffer size__1754__auto__)] (if (loop [i__149 (clojure.core/int 0)] (if (clojure.core/< i__149 size__1754__auto__) (clojure.core/let [i (clojure.core/nth c__1753__auto__ i__149)] (do (clojure.core/chunk-append b__150 i) (recur (clojure.core/unchecked-inc i__149)))) true)) (clojure.core/chunk-cons (clojure.core/chunk b__150) (iter__147 (clojure.core/chunk-rest s__148))) (clojure.core/chunk-cons (clojure.core/chunk b__150) nil))) (clojure.core/let [i (clojure.core/first s__148)] (clojure.core/cons i (iter__147 (clojure.core/rest s__148))))))))))] (iter__1755__auto__ (range 10)))
```

However, if I do the same for [doseq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq), then I get the same form back:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(doseq [i (range 10)] (println i)))
(doseq [i (range 10)] (println i))
```

But this latter expression works in Clojure as expected:

```
erdos.assert=>  (macroexpand '(doseq [i (range 10)] (println i)))
(loop* [seq_2318 (clojure.core/seq (range 10)) chunk_2319 nil count_2320 0 i_2321 0] (if (clojure.core/< i_2321 count_2320) (clojure.core/let [i (.nth chunk_2319 i_2321)] (do (println i)) (recur seq_2318 chunk_2319 count_2320 (clojure.core/unchecked-inc i_2321))) (clojure.core/when-let [seq_2318 (clojure.core/seq seq_2318)] (if (clojure.core/chunked-seq? seq_2318) (clojure.core/let [c__4917__auto__ (clojure.core/chunk-first seq_2318)] (recur (clojure.core/chunk-rest seq_2318) c__4917__auto__ (clojure.core/int (clojure.core/count c__4917__auto__)) (clojure.core/int 0))) (clojure.core/let [i (clojure.core/first seq_2318)] (do (println i)) (recur (clojure.core/next seq_2318) nil 0 0))))))
```

Perhaps `doseq` is like a [special form](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms) in Babashka? What is the reason for this distinction of `doseq`?

How should I modify `macroexpand` so that all macros are expanded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things are indeed specially treated in the interpreter and not implemented as regular macros. This is an historical artifact from the early beginnings when babashka didn't even support macros. This may change in the future.

EDIT: this is now already fixed on master. Thanks for the PR erdos.